# Eating pasta and developing a sixpack

Tags: diet, abdominals

I know that it's very important to have a proper diet when you want to develop a sixpack. I often read that one should avoid pasta, rice, potatoes, bread and so on.

However, I like this stuff very much. Is there a way to incorporate pasta, rice, potatoes and bread into a diet which aims to develop a sixpack?

My idea is to do just more cardio, avoid sugar, alcohol completely and have enough proteins in my diet and eat much veggies and little fat.

Does this have a chance to work? Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: I just found this article: http://www.sixpackfactory.com/cutting-out-carbs-is-it-dangerous/

Comment: The basis of that author's argument appears to be "I don't think it's a great idea" and a bunch of "just-so" anecdotes

Comment: Anecdotally, the five people I know who have six packs all eat pasta and carbs in general. Essentially, they live by the "if it fits your macros" mantra, where as long as they keep their calories in check and meet their macros, the diet is okay (in other words, the source doesn't matter, only the end macro split). This has worked well for me as well.

Comment: Highly processed food should be avoided, however, 'pasta' is about consistence, it need not be a factory product. You can make pasta from anything edible at home.

Answer (score 7):

There are a lot of diets and a lot of claims. A lot of them are simply not true.

The problem with pasta, rice, potatoes and bread is that they are high in carbohydrates and by that high in calories.
If you want to lose weight (and by that reducing the fat that covers your abs), you should try to keep your caloric intake below what you burn each day. How you reach your daily limit does not really matter, as long as your diet doesn't lack crucial nutrients.

You should also note that people (and by that the articles they write) often think of different things when they talk about the same stuff. The [bread I think about](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aSelection_of_bread_in_German_bakery.jpg) is certainly something completely different as [someone else thinks about](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aToast-3.jpg).

Cutting alcohol is a good idea, too, as it contains a lot of calories. Drinking less alcohol is always a good idea when looking from a health perspective.

Of course your abs won't develop themselves, I am not sure if cardio alone is enough. Try to incorporate some exercises into your workout that target the abs, at least in a compound style exercise. And always be wary of the [spot reduction myth](http://www.exrx.net/WeightTraining/Myths.html).

Comment: Thanks. I don't want to loose weight (BMI ~20). My fitness level is very high and I am doing a lot of strength especially ab exercises. I just want to get rid of the last belly fat to show my abs through.

Comment: Oh, the bread I think about is the same as you think about :-)...

Comment: @Sarah counts for rice and pasta, too. I think it is just a matter of time to get rid of the last layer of fat, I am just trying that myself.

Comment: @Informaficker many says it's impossible to achieve it without really restricting sugar and carbs and that it's not just about the calorie in and calorie out. Why is your advice contradictory to popular belief?

Answer (score 2):

Actually, dieting is a vast subject, and "simply cutting calories", reducing the amount of food you eat, without changing your eating patterns, does not necessairly work.

As for the proper way for losing weight, even among professionals there is no consensus. Maintaining the new weight is heven harder.

Also, youre quite a specific target - you want to drop your BF% very low (for men, abs are visible at around 10%BF, a bit more for women, but still equally hard to achieve) while most of the studies focus on obese people.

One of the theories pinpoints carbs as the main villain in the battle with fat, and after reading a whole lot of books and articles on the subject, Im willing to say that most of it makes sense.

Basically, high carb and sugar intake makes your insulin levels spike, and one of the roles of insulin is causing your body to store fat. A carb rich meal can rise your blood sugar level to a point where you cant use all of it as an energy source, and the insulin makes sure the rest is stored as fat - our glicogen stores are limited, but we can store almost unlimited fat. If your diet is very high on carbs, you may even build up partial insulin tolerance, which will keep your insulin very high just to preserve the normal blood sugar level.

This video quicky summarises the role of insulin:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mNYlIcXynwE

http://eatingacademy.com/start-here - this is a great blog full of great articles. I suggest you surf around that site - youll finish having a lot of new knowledge. There are great articles about the ketogenic diet, the causality of calorie intake imbalance and much more. The author is an M.D and he managed to get his own six pack abs, so i think its a worthy read. Especially this article: http://eatingacademy.com/nutrition/do-calories-matter tackles the problem of why does it matter what we eat and simple counting calories isnt exactly the best way to go.

Just to say, Im in the process of losing weight myself, and in around 3-4 months i lost over 20lbs, and mostly the changes in my diet would be cutting on carbs. Im still far away from my target BF%, but im not done yet :)

So while i understand your love for pasta, youd probably do better leaving it be, or at least restraining your intake. If you have to eat such carbs, try to eat small portions, even if more often - less of a insulin spike. Same, try to aim for low glicemic index products, for example try using full grain pasta isntead of the regular one. Try to educate yourself on the dieting matter, because the subject is quite vast and complex, and a simple "Ill eat less and it will be okay" is probably not a good idea.

Comment: Women carry more fat than men in different areas, such as breast tissue, so their abs are visible at a higher fat percentage than men. 10% or less is not really recommended for most women as you can start having complications such as amenorrhea.

Comment: Actually, there is no magic going on here. You consume less calories since you probably over ate on carbs to begin with. But there is nothing in fat and protein that makes you lose more fat (or less fat on carbs). So this is just plain wrong.
Among scientists there is quite a lot of concesuses, this is one of them. It is quite easy, first law of thermodynamic.

Comment: conMan - and if you read the articles i'd provided, you'd see an M.D arguing that the law of thermodynamic does not show which way the implication goes. I cant really summary this in a comment, so please follow the link: http://eatingacademy.com/nutrition/revisit-the-causality-of-obesity Also, off the top of my head, Robert K Cooper PhD in "flip the switch" claims that the carb/fat/protein ratio in things we eat does affect are hormonal balance (insulin the most obvious example). I respectfully disagreee with what you have said

Comment: JohnP - thanks, my mistake. Will fix.

Comment: K.L : Please read this: http://www.proteinpower.com/drmike/wp-content/uploads/2008/07/bray-review-of-gcbc.pdf

Comment: Firstly... '=' is not an implication, it is a equivalence. Meaning it goes both directions.
In this context it means exactly this: Energy stored = Energy eaten - energy spent . So if you want to make an argument that you lose more fat on your diet, you have to explain where that energy is going. If you can't explain that, then that does not imply magic.

Comment: Did you read what i gave you..? You clearly did not. The equation is obvious. And YES, it DOESNT include causality. Thats why explaining anything with it is useless. Also, if that exact equation was true, it would be nearly impossible to maintain ones weight. If 3500 excess calories = 1 lbs of fat, then eating just one loaf of bread too much every day would result in gaining over 8 lbs of fat a year... Yet people do not count their calories with 10kcal precision and yet maintain their weight. How can that be?

Comment: Also, if youre still on fighting me, well, i gave names of authorities that disagree with your claims, so that means that there actually is NO consensus among professionals and scientist, and i was right in saying so. And if thats the case, im just representing another "camp" in this discussion, so you cant outright say im lying or giving misleading information. I wont be adressing the review you linked, cause im not the authority to fight it, ill just quote it in the next comment. So again, I have to respectfully disagree with you.

Comment: Good Calories, Bad Calories is a scholarly book that
musters the evidence for the case against the high-fat
hypothesis for heart disease, cancer and obesity and in
favour of the carbohydrate-insulin hypothesis. The bibliography
is robust and contains a wealth of information. The
page notes provide detailed references to the sources. It is
well worth reading. The descriptions of important scientific
contributions are well written

Comment: What are you even talking about? ... do you even know what causality means? Have you even read your own article? Are you even aware that the article tries to make a point out of a public health perspective (how we can maintain weight over time), and you are argumenting how a person on caloric deficit is not going to lose weight. Do you even understand the difference here?

Good Calories, Bad Calories is not a scholarly book: http://www.cspinet.org/nah/11_02/bigfatlies.pdf . It is a book that deliberatly misinterprates, and sometimes flat out lies about some basic facts of human physiology.

Comment: I never claimed that a caloric deficit does not make people lose weight. And if I did, quote me. I claim it does matter WHAT you eat as it has an enormous impact on your metabolism and fat storage mechanisms, which is opposed to your claim that it does not matter what you eat. The bit about GCBC being a scholarly book came from the review YOU provided. Clearly YOU dont know what Im talking about, but that does not mean I dont. I see no point in further discussion, as you seem to be here not to discuss, but to prove me wrong and make a crusade about how you are right.

Comment: ""simply cutting calories" does not necessairly work"

Comment: What you eat has less importance to caloric deficit, if you are not in caloric deficit you will not lose weight. I am here to correct an error you made. And as long as we are clear with the caloric deficit, then that is fine by me.

Comment: Well, the study you provided shown an example of a woman who said she ate a caloric deficit and gained weight. Youll say she wasnt really in caloric deficit? Well, she obviously tried to be. It DIDNT WORK. While wrinting about "not working" i adressed the sustainability of such a caloric deficit and the ability of creating a balanced diet while eating tons of carbs, pasta included. In the lab it may be all fine and dandy, but youre supposed to LIVE that way. For some people eating starvational amounts of their pasta may work. For others, it may not, and they wont adhere to their diet.

Comment: Also, the same caloric deficit with different proportions of fat, carbs and protein will have a different effect on your metabolism, and here I claim that yes, lower carb intake will boost your fat metabolism and thus help you lose fat faster. It "works" better. So **simply** cutting calories aint the best way. Notice the "", its significant. The video and the articles could be summarized in: you may be overeating due to the metabolism changes made to your body by chronic exposure to vast amounts of carbs in your diet, while the same changes make your body store fat instead of expending it.

Comment: Also, the example of Peter Attalia shows the effects that a ketogenic diet can bring - and if you ask me, they are mighty fine. If you eat nothing, youll lose weight if you eat too much youll gain weight, its obvious. But WHY you eat too much and what to eat in order not to overdo it - thats one of the topics GCBC and the articles i mentioned try to tackle.

Comment: Anyhow, we cant even accurately measure our calorie intake, so basign your diet plan on it is a bit reckless, unless you plan to eat around half of your daily expenditure. how do you know how much nutrients is actually absorbed in the digestive process and how much goes out with the fecies? How do you exactly know how much a person needs and how effectively he's using the calories provided? There is so much estimation in all of those that keeping the perfect balance is nearly impossible. Rebember the 80kcal example? 8lbs a year? Thats whats not working in my (and some specialists) opinions

Comment: Check the definition of the calorie - it tells us how much energy you get if you BURN a certain about of a given substance. our bodies dont literally burn this. you can put a calorie count on petrol, but drinking it does nto make sense whatsoever

Comment: That is the most common problem with self reporting. There is a clear bias which have been shown time and time again that people report less then what they actually eat. Therefor you need systems like double label water and controlled meal plans when performing studies. That is exactly why older studies had it wrong when claiming that you could magically lose weight on caloric surplus.

Comment: Thats why I find diet plans based on diet composition rather than calorie intake work a lot better. Tested on myself - last year i made a acute calorie restricted diet and i lost 16lbs, cool. Only - i felt terrible all the time, sleepy, couldnt focus, I got a lot weaker, lost muscle mass. And after ending the diet, i sprung up 30lbs in about 8 months. This time im not limiting my calorie intake per se, i just changed my diet composition. Im not walking aroudn hungry, im energetic, feel fine, I dont notice great strength loss. If you ask me - this works better, we will see if its maintainable

Comment: So I can agree with you - a properly made didet of calorie restriction with strict enforcement can work - in the meaning that you will lose weight. But it does not work for many people in the practical sense, as because of the self reporting problem You mentiond. I think we can finally agree :)

Comment: What I agree on though is the sustainability and adherence to diet. Whatever makes you stick to the plan in the long run is good regardless of how you do it. This is where cutting down carbs is good. But there is still no magic going on, and there is still nothing inherently "bad" with carbs. Eating more protein keeps you more satiated, which makes you eat less calories.

However, eating carbs before training have shown to lower cortisol, so eating carbs for someone who trains is actually a good thing.

Comment: Absolutely, eating carbs before a training increases performance. And there is nothing bad per se in carbs - its just the insulin resistance effect that gets in the way, and the insulin spikes ocurring after simple carb rich meals. Thats why i suggested eating full grain pasta insead of the regular, if one wants to eat it.

Comment: The problem for most is that they try to keep the mealpattern and just lower the calories. What happens is  when you stop dieting you start to overeat again since the pattern is the same. Therefor changing the whole pattern around eating is a way to make substantial change in the long run.

I would say what would probably make most impact for most is to eat only breakfast, lunch and dinner. Keeping one of the meals low. That keeps most in maintanance on almost any diet.

Comment: I tried to clean up my answer a bit and clarify on the point i was trying to make. If need be, a mod could "clean up" our discussion in the comments

Comment: I would point out that extended comments such as this are not recommended, and should have been taken to chat instead.

Comment: I can't keep it to myself: [Twinkie Diet](http://edition.cnn.com/2010/HEALTH/11/08/twinkie.diet.professor/).

Comment: Cool story ;) Still, if you eat around half of what youre supposed to, you will lose weight, but thats rather not maintainable in the long run. Also, he cheated, he had protein shakes :P

Answer (score 2):

Why not try a body recomposition program.

A well-defined six pack is well-built muscles and a low fat percentage. A way to attain this is to eat 500kcal above maintenance levels on training days and 500kcal below maintenance on non-training days, training each other day so that the net balance is zero over the week.

To build the muscles you need to hit them with hypertrophy training. Cardio is detrimental towards that goal. It puts a lot of stress on your body which really should be resting and building muscles.

Try to eat somewhere around 1.5g protein per kg lean body mass, which also helps towards building muscles. As long as you hit your protein, the rest can be pasta, rice or whatever you like to eat which helps you keep the diet plan.

As long as you are in a net equivalence, or in net deficit, This will, albeit slowly, gain you some muscles and lose fat, leading towards a six pack.

Comment: Why no high impact cardio?

Comment: It will put quite a lot of stress on your body. If you want to gain a little mass (or even keep mass) it will most likely be detrimental towards that goal. Also, unless you are seriously well trained it will most likely be too hard training pushing you towards overtraining.

Answer (score -1):

Having visible abs is all about having low body fat, and having low body fat is all about eating fewer calories than your body consumes in a day. It doesn't matter (much) what foods you eat, as long as you're eating fewer calories.

Comment: Not true. What you eat is all a BIG difference in body composition. You can lose weight and lose half of it on lean muscle mass. Aint it a lot better to lose mostly fat? A high carb low protein diet with acute calorie intake restrictions is a sure way to lose muscle mass, ESPECIALLY taking into account that Sarah said she's doing strength training in one of the comments. Ill link some articles on the topic later

Comment: She said in the original that she intended to make sure she had enough protein in her diet. It's entirely possible to eat at a deficit, eat high-carb foods, and get enough protein.

Comment: @DocFaustus - There is a large difference between what you wrote in your comment, and what you stated in your "answer", which was basically "Eat anything you want, as long as it's a deficit."